# How can I type Japanese characters?

Tags: language-support, ibus, input-language, special-characters, japanese

What is the way to be able to type Japanese characters? Could someone make a how-to in order to explain the few steps to get it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since Ubuntu 9.10, you just have to follow those few steps :

- Install [ibus-anthy](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ibus-anthy)
- Go to System -> Preferences -> Keyboard input methods
- Accept to activate iBus (pop-up window)
- Add Japanese-Anthy in the Method tab
- Disconnect and reconnect
- Open an input field (like Gedit for instance), hit Control + Space ; you should be able to type Japanese characters

In order to have iBus launched automatically on boot, go to System -> Administration -> Languages and select iBus as the input method.

Comment: In 11.04+ is there any way to consolidate the ibus keyboard layout icon with the regular layout selector icon?

Comment: What is meant by 'disconnect and reconnect' please?

Answer (score 5):

To install Japanese input methods (Hiragana, Katagana, etc.) you need Mozc:

```bsh
# apt install fcitx-mozc ibus-mozc mozc-data mozc-server mozc-utils-gui
```

In case you can select Japanese input methods but you are missing Japanese characters - i.e. you see empty squares or other incorrect characters instead expected Hiragana, Katagana signs etc. - follow:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Installing_Japanese_character_sets

In my case installing Takao fonts solved the issue:

```bsh
# apt-get install fonts-takao
```

Comment: BTW, Mozc doesn't support a handwriting method.

Comment: this worked on Ubuntu 22.04.03 LTS.  Did not need the second command for fonts

Answer (score 0):

Read the following:

- [Japanese Input](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JapaneseInput)
- [SCIM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SCIM)