# How can I have my Ubuntu completely in Japanese (plus the standard typing)?

Tags: language-support, internationalization, japanese

hez

So my question is: I want my Ubuntu to be completely Japanese. When I installed it, I have chosen *Japanese* as the default language.. (it is in a virtual box, btw). So now everything is Japanese, no problem, the only thing is that I can't type Japanese...

Yes, I have read similar questions like "how to type Japanese", but I don't want to type using lots of key combinations like Ctrl+F6 or other stuff (I'm not a pro of course, I simply don't know what would happen if I did this ^^), but with the standard typing method (sorry I don't know it's name). Any ideas on how to do that?

I have already searched a lot on the internet and I have asked a relative of mine, who is an expert, and we didn't get it.

Comment: I Have done "japanes kana" as option, but it onlz types  katakana.. o.o

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary measure you could set up Japanese input using anthy [explained on this page.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31094/how-can-i-type-japanese-characters)

Choose your favourite keyboard shortcut (I personally use Crtl+Space) and go into the advanced tab. From here, check the option "share the same input method among all applications." Now, you'll only need to hit the shortcut once.

I tested this myself, and it will only turn on if there is somewhere that you are typing, so when you launch your first application, hit the combination and you should be sorted for the rest of your session.