# How can I type in japanese on Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, language-support, japanese

I just started learning japanese and I want to be able to type in japanese to practice. I installed japanese from the language support but when I go into keyboard input methods I cannot add japanese because the option is locked.

Comment: Have you logged out from the session and logged in again (or rebooted)?

Answer (score 4):

First complete install Japanese language

```
sudo apt install language-pack-ja --install-suggests
```

[Installing Japanese language support from command-line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567413/installing-japanese-language-support-from-command-line)

Then next, install input method

```
sudo apt install fcitx-mozc --install-suggests
```

[How can I type Japanese characters?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31094/how-can-i-type-japanese-characters?rq=1)

This old question is still useful, in my opinion, fcitx-mozc works wiser and efficient than ibus-anthy (it's rather light weight)

Answer (score 3):

install `fcitx-mozc`:

```
sudo apt install fcitx-mozc
```

[image]

open **Language Support**, set **Keyboard input method system** to **fcitx**.

open **Input Method Configuration** and **Input Method** tag, choose **Mozc** from **Available Input Method** list.

(you can find it when **Only Show Current Language** is unchecked)

then, open **Global Config** tab,and set **Trigger Input Method**.
(tap the empty button,and click a key whatever you like)

Now you can type in Japanese, I think.

Answer (score 2):

There should be a little flag or a two letter country code on your LXPanel.  Right click it and choose "Keyboard Layout Handler" settings.  Uncheck "Keep system layouts" on the right side of the new window.  Then select Add on the left side of the window.  Another window will pop up and you will choose JP for Japanese.  After it shows up move it up or down depending upon where you want it to be.  You can also select how you want this to be displayed in your LXPanel, whether you want a flag or a country code, and how big you want the icon.  Re-check "Keep system layouts".  A warning will pop up telling you that your changes will not take effect until a new session.  Close.

Answer (score 1):

I did this: downloaded japanese from language support,on keyboard input methods (Ibus preferences). I checked "customize active input methods", clicked on "select an input method" then "show all input methods" clicked on japanese, then Anthy and added it.

Answer (score 0):

Related:
Note that there is a bug, linked to below, on Ubuntu 18.04 that prevents switching keyboard input language (and causes the system to hang).  With this bug you won't be able to type in Japanese, even with all the installations and configurations posted above/previously done correctly.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mate/+bug/1740640